# CGaffinetransform reset when UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I am following a [tutorial](http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2012/02/13/an-one-finger-rotation-gesture-recognizer/) to make a rotation control.

Currently I added `image.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;` so that the image resets and rotates to the original state when the gesture ended successfully. How can I reset the image to the original state when UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed?

I've tried adding the following into `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` but it's not working.

```
if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
    OneFingerRotationGestureViewController *oneFingerRotationGestureViewController = 
      [[OneFingerRotationGestureViewController alloc] init];
    oneFingerRotationGestureViewController.image.transform = 
       CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` means that the gesture recognizer never recognized its gesture, so it did nothing. In other words, if the gesture recognizer failed, the image never moved, so there is no work to do.

Comment: How about if the gesture is recognized in the beginning but doesn't at the end? For example in this picture, the user drags finger to area outside the black circle at the end of the control. How can I reset the image when such thing happens? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42966106/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-01%20at%2011.14.19%20am.png